# Cant route to other view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

**Description:** I created a picture of flag where user is able to change to different language. it should route to another view which is completely the same but only the language is different

**Problem:** It doesn't route me to another view, although it does take me back to the original one.

Index.cshtml

```
<li>
   <a 
      href='@Url.RouteUrl("Lietuviu")'>
      <img src="/Content/img/lie.png" />
   </a>
</li>
```

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute("Lietuviu", "", new { controller = "Home", action= "Lietuviu" });
```

HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Lietuviu() 
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The view is named Lietuviu and added to the Views/Home/. I decided to use the same home controller as I will only have 2 pages.
**I tried:** Creating seperate controller for the view, making sure that everything is named properly, tried `Url.Action()` method instead of `Url.RouteUrl()`

Comment: View/Home/ isn't correct. it's ViewS/Home/Lietuviu.cshtml

Comment: Sorry, it was the typo. It is Views/Home/Lietuviu.cshtml

Comment: Can you show more code ? All your route configuration.

Comment: It seems that it was build mistake, it now changes to the translated page but it doesnt keep style. Appereantly english view also lost style somehow

Answer (score 0):

Your route isn't correct, you need to precise a path.

```
routes.MapRoute("Lietuviu", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action= "Lietuviu" });
```

Comment: I replaced my route with this one and now it only goes to the unstyled version of english.

Comment: did you change the `href` back to `/Home/Lietuviu/`.